# How to create a solution with different project references (choice between a NuGet compiled or a project)?

Tags: visual-studio

I have this solution with two kind of projects, say A and B. Projects B are projects that can be referenced as a real projects (with code and all) OR from a NuGet package (for other developers that don't have to debug Projects B).

It is possible for type "A" Visual Studio Project to understand if to use the compiled dlls from NuGet or (if installed) the complete B projects? I know there are some kind of conditional helpers manually modifying the CSProj files, but the "A" projects are a lot and often created from scratch. My idea was to create a software to manually modify the CSProj, but I fear that's not the cleanest thing to do.

Is there something official or I'm missing something?

Thank you!
Alberto

Answer (score 0):

One can simply use the  csproj element: using a condition based on a compilation symbol, creating two configurations, one can select between reading a nuget package or a project reference. Just remember to use NuGet package referenced from csproj instead of packages.config